# How to Perform Subtraction in SQL query based on some conditions?

Tags: mysql

I want to sum up `qty*price` where type is 'in' and then subtract the sum of `qty*price` where type is 'out'. Something like this.
`SELECT cid, name, SUM(paid_amt), (SELECT SUM(qty*price) WHERE type = 'in' - SELECT SUM(qty*price) WHERE type = 'out'), type FROM`transactions`GROUP BY cid`
Here's is my SQL query.

Comment: A tricky way: `SUM(qty*price * ((type = 'in') - (type = 'out')))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your problem by using two different `sum` expressions, each with a slightly different case statement inside of it. The idea is that your case statement only returns a value to the aggregate sum expression if it's of the correct typing.

```sql
select
  cid
  , sum(case when type = "in" then qty*price else 0 end) 
  - sum(case when type = "out" then qty*price else 0 end)
from
  your_table
group by
  cid
```